# why windows gitlab runner build repository with crlf?

Tags: node.js, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

1. How to keep same line ending when .gitlab runner clone project in local directory?
2. i have dockerFile on remote repository with LF ending. but when i run jobs in .gitlab-ci.yml then cloned reopository chnage LF to crlf in windows.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to turn off automatic line ending conversion for the user running the GitLab CI jobs.

As that user account, run `git config --global core.autocrlf false`.

This will make all git checkouts performed by this user keep the line endings that are in the repository.

Comment: i tried "git config --global core.autocrlf false" . but it not works. again when repository download on windows directory it change LF to CRLF